# Script in mpi4py not executing correctly

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, mpi4py

I'm developing a cluster using mpi4py and when i run a basic script to test the cluster the result is weird:

[image]

the result should be this (script executed in c):

[image]

My code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

world_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
world_size = world_comm.Get_size()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
my_rank = world_comm.Get_rank()

print('World Size: {0} | Name: {1} | Rank: {2}'.format(world_size,name,my_rank))
```

And the hostfile:

```
no02   slots=3 
no01   slots=5
```

How could I get around this problem?

Comment: This usually happens when you use an `mpiexec` that doesn't belong with your MPI installation. When you installed mpi4py, did it leave an mpiexec somewhere? Try using that one.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout thanks for the comments, I reinstalled mpi4py this time by passing the MPICC in the env and it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it as follows: I reinstalled mpi4py, but this time I passed the MPICC env before installation:

`env MPICC=/usr/bin/mpicc pip3 install mpi4py --no-cache-dir`

But you need to make sure the `libopenmpi-dev` library is installed and then run the `which mpicc` command and put it as a path in the `env` in the above command